# Why MySql SUBDATE(now(3), 2) function is adding extra three digits in milliseconds?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
set @currentdatetime:=now(3);
set @intervalStartDate:=subdate(@currentdatetime, 2);

select @currentdatetime, @intervalStartDate;
```

These queries gives the following output:

```
|   @currentdatetime        |      @intervalStartDate       | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2018-04-15 13:02:32.948    |    2018-04-13 13:02:32.948000 |
```

Why three extra zeros are added in the end of `@intervalStartDate`?

How can I remove these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Why three extra zeros are added in the end?:-

Whenever SUBDATE() function is called with milliseconds(any precision) in DATETIME parameter, it will compute and assign the output in maximum precision limit for milliseconds.(from one of the answers of this question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49874173/6355028))

2) How can I remove these?

Instead of storing a value of `now()` in a variable and passing it into `subdate()`, directly pass `now()` into `subdate()`
,i.e., replace

```
set @currentdatetime:=now(3);
set @intervalStartDate:=subdate(@currentdatetime, 2);
```

with this

```
set @intervalStartDate:=subdate(now(3), 2);
```

but if you want to store a value of `now()` in a variable first, then one workaround to remove trailing zero is `trim` of mysql.

```
set @currentdatetime:=now(3);
set @intervalStartDate:=trim(trailing '0' from subdate(@currentdatetime, 2));
```

see demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1f217/4)

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` function has a max limit of 6 decimal places for milliseconds.

```
SELECT NOW(6);
```

gives something like:

```
2018-04-17 13:43:55.067047
```

Whenever SUBDATE() function is called with milliseconds(any precision) in DATETIME parameter, it will compute and assign the output in maximum precision limit for milliseconds.